# Range or index out of bounds crash when i'm a delegate for my NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a textfield for which i'd like to clear the input if the word 'ERROR' has been put in there.

I have made my ViewController the delegate and have setup the following method.

```
- (void)controlTextDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)obj {
    if ([[txtCode stringValue] isEqual:@"ERROR"]) {
        [txtCode setStringValue:@""];
    }
}
```

Every time the first character is pressed in that text field, regardless of what's in it (ie even if it doesn't have the word 'ERROR' in it), the app crashes with:

```
[General] -[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

I have narrowed it down to the if statement, or really this line:

```
[[txtCode stringValue] isEqual:@"ERROR"]
```

is what's causing the crash, but I can't understand why?

Comment: When the app crashes, the stack trace should show you the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: Nothing in there linking directly to my code... the only thing i have found is that remarking that if statement disabled this problem.

Comment: The exception is on `[txtCode setStringValue:@""];`, registering undo is using the old selected range.

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain what you mean? I don't understand.  Also if i comment just that line out, i still have the problem.  The problem only goes away if i comment the if statement out.

Comment: Undo is registered after `[txtCode setStringValue:@""]` with the selected range before `[txtCode setStringValue:@""]`. Post a [mre] without  `[txtCode setStringValue:@""]` please.